# -lidn error after adding xmpp framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xmppframework, xmpp4r

I am getting this issue after adding XMPP framework. I tried all the answers on stack overflow and other sites as well but did not find the solution.

Comment: OK look (in the build log) at the `-L` options being passed to the linker then check those directories for the file `libidn.a`.  If you find it, check it's architecture (using `file` from the command line) and report back.

Comment: I checked everything is right...

Comment: Well I don't think it is...

Comment: Do I need to share screenshots to u ?